# Suppose $f:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $p$. Prove that if $f(p) > 0$, then there is $\delta>0$ s.t. $f(x) \geq f(p)/2$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $f:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $p$.  Prove that if $f(p) > 0$, then there is $\delta>0$ s.t. $f(x) \geq f(p)/2$ $\forall x$ in $E$ s.t. $|x-p| \leq \delta$.

I couldn't find other questions like it and I can't quite figure it out.  I recognize that I am given that $f$ is continuous and so that allows me to play with the $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ to try and make the desired result pop up but i'm not quite sure how to.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\epsilon=f(p)/2$. By the definition of continuity at point $p$ there exists $\delta>0$ so that for all $x\in E $ with $|x-p|<\delta$ we have $|f(x)-f(p)|<\epsilon=f(p)/2$.

In particular $f(x)-f(p)>-f(p)/2\implies f(x)>f(p)/2$

Comment: Okay, that made it look simple.  Playing with the absolute values gives the desired result.  What would I need to do to show that it is $f(x) \geq f(p)/2$?  Is there a difference?

Comment: What I did shows that $f(x)\geq f(p)/2$. Notice that $f(x)>f(p)/2$ implies $f(x)\geq f(p)/2$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, if $f$ is continuous at $p$, then $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ such that

$$
f(p)-\varepsilon<f(x)<f(x)+\varepsilon
$$

$\forall x\in (p-\delta,p+\delta)$. Can you come up with a suitable $\varepsilon$ that helps you prove the statement?